# Trying to uninstall module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to uninstall a module but I am getting this error in a report

```
a:4:{i:0;s:67:"Setup version for module 'Bss_CheckoutCustomField' is not specified";i:1;s:3854:"#0 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(56): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Bss_CheckoutCus...', false)
#1 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/DbVersionInfo.php(79): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Bss_CheckoutCus...')
#2 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(55): Magento\Framework\Module\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()
#3 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#5 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#8 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'infortis_cgen_m...')
#11 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/app/code/Infortis/Cgen/Plugin/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(32): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Infortis\Cgen\Plugin\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#14 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#16 /home/mobilityhire/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#17 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Could someone possibly assist?

Comment: Please specify how you uninsstall it?

Comment: I deleted the module from the 'code' folder inside the app folder, deleted the module entry from the 'setup_module' table, ran a 'magento setup:upgrade' and re-deployed the static content, could I be doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please remove `var/generation`. and check again.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted 'var/generation', ran a 'setup:di:compile' but still getting the same error :/

Comment: Check for `Bss_CheckoutCustomField` in your `app/etc/config.php` file.  If found, the value should be 0.  Also, you can delete any entries in your database that could cause the problem with this: `delete from setup_module where module = 'Bss_CheckoutCustomField';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to uninsall a module in magento 2 you have to remove it from your database by running following sql script

`delete from setup_module where module = 'Bss_CheckoutCustomField'`

furthermore you have to check if the module is defined in `MAGENTO_FOLDER/app/etc/config.php` ... if there is a line for your module delete the line or set it to 0 and save the file.

re-run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`